# How to open up Windows Explorer and specify location in Shell

Tags: windows, shell

I want to be able to make a little shell script that will open some windows explorers at a specified location and with a specific size.

So far, I have:

```
explorer c:\
```

that will open a new windows explorer at "c:\"

I can't find any documentation as to how to specify the location and size of the window.

Is this possible under **Windows 7**?

Thanks!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg314982(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Microsoft Support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/130510), there is no way to do this directly with the Explorer executable. You'd need to externally get a handle to the opened window and use the WinAPI [MoveWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.

Comment: Thanks, but I think that article might be too old...
Article ID: 130510 - Last Review: January 19, 2007 - Revision: 1.4
APPLIES TO
Microsoft Windows 95
Microsoft Windows NT Server 4.0 Standard Edition
Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 4.0 Developer Edition
Microsoft Windows 98 Standard Edition
Microsoft Windows 98 Second Edition
Microsoft Windows Millennium Edition

Comment: Err, whoops. I can't actually seem to find any official article which is any newer than for Windows XP. None of the third-party references mention any kind of command-line switch for moving the window, though. [Here's an example of one out of many](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/shell/explorer/cmdline.htm).